# Corosync dependency on unmanaged service

Tags: linux, centos-7, cluster

I'm trying to build an HA syslog cluster.

UDP syslog being stateless, there is no way for a balancer to ensure liveness of the nodes, so I'm experimenting with PCS/Corosync on CentoOS7.

Ideally, I would want the cluster software to detect a rsyslog failure on a node. After detection, the cluster would fail the IP resource over to one of the remaining node.

What I've been able to do is quite different. I added a 'systemd' resource for rsyslog, then 'cloned' it to be able to keep it running on both nodes. When I put a node in standby to perform maintenance or tests, the rsyslog service on that node is shutdown.

rsyslog is a system service, I don't want the cluster to manage it, but I cannot find a way to do otherwise.

Is there a way to add a 'virtual' dependency to the cluster, so that a shared resource (i.e. IP Address) can be run on a node only if a particular service is running (or a port is listening, or whatever), without letting the cluster take ownership of the service lifecycle?

I think I can write a simple shell script to detect whether my 'external' dependency is running or not, but where should I put it inside a Corosync cluster?

Thanks in advance

Angelo.